# Different Array sum ifs custom function dependant on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following 2 formulas dependent on what is in column B, however I need to add this as a UDF and am struggling:

If the value in `B3` is  `"Cat A"` I use this formula:

```
{=(((SUM(IF(('Photo Data'!$E$3:$E$2000='Summary'!$C3)*('Photo Data'!$F$3:$F$2000="Monthly Cost"),'Photo Data'!$G$3:$R$2000)))))}
```

If the value is `"Cat B"` I use this formula:

```
{=(((SUM(IF(('Latest Data'!$G$3:$G$2000='Summary'!$C3)*('Latest Data'!$H$3:$H$2000="Monthly Cost")*('Latest Data'!$E$3:$E$1982="MAT"),'Latest Data'!$I$3:$T$2000,0)))))}
```

I will be using dynamic ranges for the Latest Data & Photo Data. I know I can do an *if* within this but I will eventually have 10 different categories (Cat A-J) and want to start using UDF's

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started on your ten-part UDF.

```
Function udf_SumIfs(rCAT As Range)
    'application.volatile
    Dim sFORMULA As String
    Dim sWS As String, sRW As String

    sRW = rCAT.Row
    Select Case rCAT.Value2
        Case "Cat A"
            sFORMULA = "sum(if('×ws×'!$E$3:$E$2000='Summary'!$C×rw×, if('×ws×'!$F$3:$F$2000=""Monthly Cost"", '×ws×'!$G$3:$R$2000)))"
            sWS = "Photo Data"
            sFORMULA = Replace(Replace(sFORMULA, "×ws×", sWS), "×rw×", sRW)
            udf_SumIfs = Application.Evaluate(sFORMULA)
        Case "Cat B"
            sFORMULA = "sum(if('×ws×'!$G$3:$G$2000='Summary'!$C×rw×, if('×ws×'!$H$3:$H$2000=""Monthly Cost"", if('×ws×'!$E$3:$E$2000=""MAT"", '×ws×'!$I$3:$T$2000))))"
            sWS = "Latest Data"
            sFORMULA = Replace(Replace(sFORMULA, "×ws×", sWS), "×rw×", sRW)
            udf_SumIfs = Application.Evaluate(sFORMULA)
        Case Else
            udf_SumIfs = "no Cats allowed"
    End Select

End Function
```

The [Application Evaluate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx) function evaluates every formula passed into it as an array formula so there is no need to specify anything array specific.

I've left the [Application.Evaluate method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx) commented. If the UDF is not being refreshed correctly, uncomment this code line. Usually a UDF will update when cells that affect it change and this is unnecessary but a number of the rage references are hard-coded within the UDf and changes to them will not trigger an update.

Use as any native worksheet formula. e.g.,

```
=udf_SumIfs(B3)
```